# SQL get results 21-30?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, limit

This seems like a really simple question but I can't seem to find information on it.

If I have 100 results, and I only want to get the results results between 21 and 30 (from the order my SQL query is grabbing them), how would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
LIMIT 20, 10
```

E.g.,

```
select *
from MyTable
LIMIT 20, 10
```